# InstantiationError for multipart / form-data ; Request client to server

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, multipartform-data

I implemented an user interface and a webservice. The communication is with rest and both are running on a tomcat server. If I want to send a request, I get an error:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Root Cause

java.lang.InstantiationError: org.apache.james.mime4j.message.BodyFactory
org.apache.james.mime4j.message.MessageBuilder.<init>(MessageBuilder.java:56)
org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Message.<init>(Message.java:140)
org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Message.<init>(Message.java:100)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl.parse(MultipartInputImpl.java:76)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataReader.readFrom(MultipartFormDataReader.java:52)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataReader.readFrom(MultipartFormDataReader.java:20)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:66)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ServerReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(ServerReaderInterceptorContext.java:61)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:56)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:123)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:59)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:147)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:92)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:115)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:294)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:248)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:235)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:398)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:205)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:228)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Frontendpart:

```
 function uploadFile(url, data){
            console.log(url);
            return $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                headers: {
                    "Authorization" : "Bearer " + window.sessionStorage.getItem("authToken"),
                    "User"  : window.sessionStorage.getItem("userID")
                }
            })
        }
```

Backendpart:

```
    @POST
    @Path("url")
    @PermitAll
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public static Response uploadEvents(MultipartFormDataInput input, @Context HttpHeaders headers) throws Exception {
}
```

Allready tried to set multipart/form-data in frontend contenttype, but also get this error message.

Local configuration is running. On a webserver it runs into the error message, if I use that function.

EDIT: 
After I updated my POM with new restay version 3.9.0.Final, the error changed into:

```
The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.</p><p><b>Exception</b></p><pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre><p><b>Root Cause</b></p><pre>java.lang.InstantiationError: org.apache.james.mime4j.message.BodyFactory
    org.apache.james.mime4j.message.MessageBuilder.&lt;init&gt;(MessageBuilder.java:56)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl$BinaryOnlyMessageBuilder.&lt;init&gt;(MultipartInputImpl.java:112)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl$BinaryOnlyMessageBuilder.&lt;init&gt;(MultipartInputImpl.java:81)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl$BinaryMessage.&lt;init&gt;(MultipartInputImpl.java:183)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl$BinaryMessage.&lt;init&gt;(MultipartInputImpl.java:169)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl.parse(MultipartInputImpl.java:235)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataReader.readFrom(MultipartFormDataReader.java:53)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataReader.readFrom(MultipartFormDataReader.java:23)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:66)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ServerReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(ServerReaderInterceptorContext.java:61)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:56)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:123)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:59)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:147)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:92)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:115)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:294)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:248)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:235)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:398)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:205)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:228)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre><p><b>Note</b> The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.45</h3></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My war file had 2 identify jar files with different versions. I had to delete the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the Above Exception. Check With the jar if you are having
apache-mime4j-*.jar and you are also having
apache-mime4j-core-*.jar
apache-mime4j-dom-*.jar

if you remove the core and dom jar your issue will resolve.